# I want to update a newid to a column based on a part of string for a table which has 2000 rows

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE ex e
SET e.parentId IN (SELECT p.id 
                   FROM parent p  
                   WHERE p.attributeName IN 
                         (SELECT regexp_substr(attributeName,'[^.]+') from ex));
```

Comment: Pls improvie your question: What you want to achive and what is the problem yo have with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is for MySQL

```
UPDATE ex as e inner join parent p  
on p.attributeName = regexp_substr(e.attributeName,'[^.]+') ; 
set e.parentId = p.id
```